# the system cannot find the file specified unable to start the docker

Tags: docker

I have installed the docker for `Windows 10 home`, After installation when I try to open the Docker Terminal the following error pops up.

`open C:\Users\shani\.docker\machine\machines\default\config.json: The system cannot find the file specified. Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...`

I cannot find `config.json` anywhere. I tried finding the online solution but in all of those solutions the docker runs and then while pulling some images, it creates this problem. I also tried t add the file with following  content in it (Solution I found online)
`{ }`
But It does not work? What should I do here?

Comment: Can you find the path `C:/Program Files/Docker Toolbox` in your system?

Comment: @Ayush28 Yes, the folder and its content exist.